# X-Axis Format in Kendo-UI

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

I have started on Telerik Kendo. I have put some data to display. However X axis is readable in the current format. How could I format it?

```
<base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/line-charts/date-axis">
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.408/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.408/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <body>
            <div id="example">
                <div class="demo-section k-content">
                    <div id="chart"></div>
                </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <script>
                    var stats = [
                        { x: 0, y: 0 },
                        { x: -3.88770423666098, y: 945.987507963258 },
                        { x: -4.24922990437403, y: 985.985280150689 },
                        { x: -2.91182688405784, y: 1080.9534171457 },
                        { x: 1.90405053850085, y: 1175.79962223412 },
                        { x: 7.80045299498725, y: 1270.59074063256 },

                    ];

                    function createChart() {
                        $("#chart").kendoChart({
                            title: {
                                text: "Units sold"
                            },
                            dataSource: {
                                data: stats
                            },
                            series: [{
                                type: "line",
                                field: "x",
                                categoryField: "y"
                            }],

                        });
                    }

                    $(document).ready(createChart);
                    $("#example").bind("kendo:skinChange", createChart);
                </script>
            </div>
    </body>
```

Here is jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/nDS3S/23/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an area chart and format the labels to suit your needs:

```
function createChart() {
                $("#chart").kendoChart({
                    title: {
                        text: "Units sold"
                    },
                    dataSource: {
                        data: stats
                    },                        
                    categoryAxis: {                            
                        labels: {                                
                            step: 10,
                            format: "n2"
                        },
                    },
                    series: [{
                        type: "area",
                         line: {
                            style: "smooth"
                        },
                        field: "x",
                        categoryField: "y"
                    }], 
                });
 }
```

I had set the type to `area`, the line type to `smooth`, and the `labels to skip 10 positions`, and to show `two decimal digits`.

I have updated your
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nDS3S/26/)

Thanks.

Comment: Any idea of the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30144782/tooltip-with-multiple-parameters-in-kendo-ui