# Tooltip Template Formating in Kendo-UI

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have the following code, and initially my data consists only `x` and `y` values, however, once I added another value which is `k` but it stopped working. I am planning to display `k` value as an additional information into tooltip. 
Does anybody has any idea?

```
function createChart() {
    $("#chart")
        .kendoChart({
            xAxis: {},
            yAxis: {},
            seriesDefaults: {type: "scatterLine" },
            series: [{data: stats}],
            tooltip:{visible:true,template: "#= myTooltip(value) # "}
        });
}

function myTooltip(value) {
    return Math.abs(value.x) + ", "+Math.abs(value.y)+","+Math.abs(value.k);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3yhbyy2g/49/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, here is the solution that I have come up so far. The key-point here is to access data via `dataItem` not via `value-->(value.x, value.y)` that restricts to access other elements in data objects other than only `x` and `y`.

It seems that `value` inherits from `dataItem`.

```
 tooltip:
     {
     visible:true,
     template: 
       "x : #=kendo.format('{0:n0}', (Math.abs(dataItem.x)))#, 
        y : #=kendo.format('{0:n0}', (Math.abs(dataItem.y)))#, 
        k : #=kendo.format('{0:n0}', (Math.abs(dataItem.k)))# "
     }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3yhbyy2g/50/